# Record video with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm not sure what I should put in the method

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

In order to write the frames to a video. Can anybody share with me the body of their code for this method, where the results is recording the frames to a movie?

I thought I had my assetWriter and videoInput setup correctly, but all I'm getting is a movie with 1 frame used repeatedly.

Comment: Check out the AVCamDemo code from WWDC 2010. It has an example that will show you what to do.

Comment: If you don't need to actually inspect/modify/display the frames you could replace the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVAssetWriter with the simpler AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.

Answer (score 7):

Check the Apple Sample Code [Rosy Writer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110). Its a very good example of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can successfully recording a video and grabbing frames at the same time using this method:

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice new];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput new];
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];


NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:640], AVVideoWidthKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoHeightKey, AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput  assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:outputSettings];


/ AVCaptureVideDataOutput /
AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *pixelBufferAdaptor =
           [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc] 
                initWithAssetWriterInput:assetWriterInput 
                sourcePixelBufferAttributes:
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], 
                           kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                     nil]];


/* Asset writer with MPEG4 format*/
AVAssetWriter *assetWriterMyData = [[AVAssetWriter alloc]
                                initWithURL:URLFromSomwhere
                                fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                error:you need to check error conditions,
                                      this example is too lazy];
[assetWriterMyData addInput:assetWriterInput];
assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

/ Start writing data /

[assetWriterMyData startWriting];
[assetWriterMyData startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
[captureSession startRunning];



- (void)        captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    // a very dense way to keep track of the time at which this frame
    // occurs relative to the output stream, but it's just an example!
    static int64_t frameNumber = 0;
    if(assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
        [pixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:imageBuffer
                         withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frameNumber, 25)];
    frameNumber++;
}

/* To stop recording, stop capture session and finish writing data*/

[captureSession stopRunning];
[assetWriterMyData finishWriting];
```